# converted JS array to JSON object but not able to read that json object at java servelet end

Tags: javascript, json, jsp

this is javascript code to create json variable and i am not able to get how to acess  >this json variable at servlet end.

```
<script>
function()
{       alert("sending");
var Jsonobj=JSON.stringify(folderarray);
alert(Jsonobj); 
$.ajax({         url: '/Chandrayan-2014/src/Handler/FolderHandler.java'+param,
type: 'POST',
dataType: 'json',
success: function(result) { 
alert('SUCCESS');        }  }); 
alert("sent");
```

}

Comment: To me it looks like you should have a look a the `$.ajax` documentation again: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: thankss -Felix Kling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May i suggest you to use console.log instead of alert?
also, like cloudwalker said, i see your ajax call is missing the data property

```
var Jsonobj=JSON.stringify(folderarray);
console.log(Jsonobj);
$.ajax({
  'type' : 'POST',
  'url' : '/route/to/my/handler',
  'data' : Jsonobj,
  'success' : function () { console.log('succeed with args %o', arguments); },
  'error' : function () { console.log('failed with args %o', arguments); }
});
```

Note that the dataType property is used to specified the type of data that you're expecting back from the server. **Not the type of data you're submiting**

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you're actually passing the jsonobj as a parameter. You'd maybe want something like:

```
$.ajax({         url: '/myUrl',
type: 'POST',
dataType: 'json',
data: {myJsonObj: Jsonobj} --PASS THE OBJECT HERE
success: function(result) { 
alert('SUCCESS');        }  }); 
alert("sent");
```

I'm also a little confused about your url. Are you trying to link directly to a java source file, or did you just set up a servlet mapping that has .java at the end?

Comment: Yes I have setup the servelet mappinglike this only.I have tried your option its not working .How can I know wether I am recieving this Json Object at servlet end or no ???